# Detecting Real Click For URLs Within Gmail HTML Page

Tags: html, http, gmail, sendmail, sendgrid

I am sending emails to customers that have HTML tags in them.

```
<a href="https://example.com/xyz" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://example.com/xyz&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1630670728276000&amp;usg=AGEQSDF-AWAS#">Click Here</a>
```

On my endpoint, I want to know whether it was the user who actually clicked on the email in Gmail or it was some email URL analysis platform or Email Gateway Solutions.

When the user clicks the link in my email, first of all, it opens URL `https://www.google.com/url?q=https://example.com/xyz&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1630670728276000&amp;usg=AGEQSDF-AWAS#` and then it gets redirected to the actual URL. After redirecting when it sends a GET request to my endpoint, the following headers are sent to my server. It does not have any referrer URL that can help me to determine whether the user actually clicked on it.

```
GET /xyz HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Te: trailers
Connection: close
```

How will I solve my problem of detecting real click ( GET Request) rather than some URL Analysis click?

Comment: It is unlikely you can check that. If the link is clicked by humans or non-humans, you do not have for example JavaScript that can help because that is not executed in emails. Best bet is to show a page in between and have the user click that to confirm

Comment: any other way to add referrer in the request ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

If you are sending your emails with SendGrid (which I guess you are because you tagged the question "sendgrid") then you could enable [open and click tracking from within your SendGrid account](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/tracking), then you can set up to receive the [event webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event). If you also send your emails with a unique identifier in the [custom arguments](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations) then you can tie each open and click to the unique email. It might not be perfect, but you could implement some heuristics, like checking that an email is opened before you accept clicks.

I don't think there's any way to add headers to the request once the user is directed through the google.com redirect.